# Reverse direction of loop through an array containing functions, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have the following **Javascript** which aims to enable users to cycle backwards and forwards through a number of menus using an `array` of functions executed by an `eventListener`...

```
var i = 0;
var steps = [
  function one() {do something},
  function two() {do something},
  function three() {do something},
  function four() {do something},
  function five() {do something}
]
//loops forward through array *successfully*
document.getElementById('forward').addEventListener("click", function() {
  steps[i]();
}
//loops backwards through array *unsuccessfully*
document.getElementById('backward').addEventListener("click", function() {
  steps[i]().reverse();
}
```

The first `eventListener` function is successful in looping through the `array`, however, the second `eventListener` function *backward*, fails to loop through the array in reverse (to little suprise).

**Firstly**, I am unsure on how to loop an `array`, that contains functions, in reverse.

**Secondly**, I am wondering if it's possible to loop an `array` in reverse from a particular point in that `array`; essentially, if the `array` has looped through, and had gone no further than *function three()*, is there a script that will allow a user to loop backwards to functions *two()* then *one()*, then forward again?

I have read a number of questions here on StackOverflow concerning array.reverse(), however none that I've found seem to concern the presence of functions and/or reversing the loop mid-array.

So thank you for any answers, they're greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your intention here is not very clear. Can you be more specific? Preferably with a [MInimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i do not see any loops...., make your functions write to console so you can see what you are doing

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5o26we3/14/) out and see if that helps. If it is, please let me know so that I can post it as an answer. Plus **if that is what you are expecting, I suggest you to read your question again and see if that is what you describe in your question**. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to loop over the array. You need to "manage state", which means you increment and decrement `i`. After updating the state, you find the right function using `steps[i]` and call it.

```js
var activeMenuIndex = 0;

var steps = [
  function one() {console.log("activate menu 1") },
  function two() {console.log("activate menu 2") },
  function three() {console.log("activate menu 3") },
  function four() {console.log("activate menu 4") },
  function five() {console.log("activate menu 5") }
];

var activateCurrentMenu = function() {
  var activator = steps[activeMenuIndex];
  
  if (activator) {
    activator();
  } else {
    console.log("Out of bounds!");
  }
};

var nextMenu = function() {
  // TODO: Check for out of bounds
  activeMenuIndex += 1;
  activateCurrentMenu();
};

var prevMenu = function() {
  // TODO: Check for out of bounds
  activeMenuIndex -= 1;
  activateCurrentMenu();
};


document.getElementById('forward').addEventListener("click", nextMenu);
document.getElementById('backward').addEventListener("click", prevMenu);
```

```html
<button id="backward">back</button>
<button id="forward">next</button>
```

To answer the question though: looping over an array of functions is no different than looping over any other array. You can use a `for` block, or use `foreach`.

If you want to loop over an array in reverse, you can call `.reverse().foreach` (which mutates the original array).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? Looping through array

```js
   var steps = [
    function one() { console.log("1") },
    function two() { console.log("2") },
    function three(){ console.log("3") },
    function four() { console.log("4") },
    function five() { console.log("5") }
    ]
    //loops forward through array
    function forward(i){
      steps.slice(0,i).forEach(function(el){ el(); });
    }
    //loops backwards through a the reversed aarray
    function backward(i) {
      steps.reverse().slice(0,i).forEach(function(el){ el(); });
    }

    forward(3);
    backward(3);
```